# How exactly did Peter Pettigrew plan to help Lupin?

Tags: harry-potter, animagi

We know that the reason the 3 Marauders, James Potter, Sirius Black and Peter Pettigrew, went through the process of becoming Animagi was because their friend, Remus Lupin, was a werewolf, and they wanted to both keep him company and keep him in check.

For Sirius, the big black Dog, and James, the large Stag, that makes at least some sense. Peter, on the other hand... was a rat. Just how exactly was he going to help Lupin in any way as an animal, if he's much smaller, considerably weaker physically, and unable to cast spells? Do we know?

Comment: Basically calming down the Whomping Willow so the other 2 could pass through

Comment: You might want to clarify something here - both your post and the accepted answer seem to imply that Peters rat form was a deliberate choice, which isn't correct. Maybe rephrase to "How did he help?" rather than "How did he plan to help?"

Comment: It does seem that animagi don't actually get to choose which animal they become. Peter did what he could, but his character/identity dictates that he is a rat.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Being small, inconspicious, and fast enough** in his rat form, Peter would be able to slip under The Whomping Willow's frenzied dance, hit the kill switch, thus allowing James and Sirius to pass through without getting their heads smashed.

> ‘They couldn’t keep me company as humans, so they kept me company as animals,’ said Lupin. ‘A werewolf is only a danger to people. They sneaked out of the castle every month under James’s Invisibility Cloak. They transformed, Peter, as the smallest, **could slip beneath the Willow’s attacking branches and touch the knot that freezes it**. They would then slip down the tunnel and join me.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*</sub>

He would provide **psychological support** as well to Remus during his transformations.

> ‘And they didn’t desert me at all. Instead they did something for me that would make my transformations not only bearable, but the best times of my life. They became Animagi.’
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*</sub>

Being "animals" in a sense, Lupin was not prone to attacking the Marauders, as such they were able to accompany him during his transformations.

## How did he plan on helping before becoming an Animagus?

**Uncertain**, as we know that you can't choose your Animagus form (see @Gallifreyan's answer). This is pure speculation, but it's likely he intended to provide psychological support regardless.

A werewolf is generally known for not being a threat to animals, according to Remus, at least. Knowing this, the Marauders become Animagi for Remus' sake, as they knew they would not be in danger in their animal forms, thus giving him psychological support during his transformations. So whatever animal Peter would have become he would still have been able to accompany Remus during his transformations.

Comment: Wait, so Lupin would go down first, by himself, _before_ the tree was frozen, _every_ Full Moon? And, occasionally, I imagine, whilst transforming? Damn.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I believe Madam Pomfrey/Dumbledore brings him there every Full Moon. Being experienced (more so than the Marauders), they'd know how to freeze the knot using only magic, as the Golden Trio did in *The Deathly Hallows*

Comment: Both quotes from *Prisoner of Azkaban*; here's [a book extract found on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/a-marauders-youth)

Comment: Do you mean "as they knew they would *not* be in danger" in your last paragraph?

Comment: @MissMonicaE I believe the answerer means that they became Animagi as *otherwise* they would be in danger - that is, if they tried to accompany him whilst still human. You're right though, the fragment is unclear and should probably be changed.

Comment: @Voronwë - I'm not sure about that last bit, "a werewolf is generally known for not being a threat to animals." In lots of werewolf movies the werewolves who make a human attempt to avoid hurting other people often wake up the morning after a full moon lying naked next to dead, mangled dear, covered in blood, and with a full stomach.

Comment: @KevinRubin But this is Harry Potter is it not? So that's irrelevant. And how can a werewolf make a human attempt to avoid hurting other people when they're not even in control of themselves? That's silly. And do werewolves ever eat the people they infect? Maybe they do but none of that is relevant to HP.

Answer (score 26):

People don't choose what animal to become as an animagus. The animals are random, but carry (probably) a part of the human's character, [per Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/features/everything-you-didnt-know-about-animagi):

> **You cannot choose your Animagus animal**
>
> If we could choose our Animagus, you can rest assured we’d all be lions, adorable puppies, or magnificent eagles. But realistically, an Animagus is closely linked to your personality. For example, the brave and rebellious James Potter is famously a stag, whereas the conniving journalist Rita Skeeter is a beetle.

We can see why Peter would become a rat... because he is a rat, really, since he

> betrayed Lily and James' trust and sold them to Voldemort.

The Marauders should have taken the clue.

Peter had a use though - he was small enough to sneak past the tree which was on top of the entrance to the passage to the Shrieking Shack, and press the "button" which calmed its otherwise deadly branches.